# Solving implicit function numerically

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, implicit-function

Given variables $x \in \mathbb{R}^{d_1}$, $y \in \mathbb{R}^{d_2}$ with $d_1 + d_2 = d$ and smooth functions $f_1, f_2 : \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$, I want to solve the equation
$$g_1(x,y) = -(\nabla_x f_1)(x, y-\nabla_y f_2(x+g_1(x,y), y))$$
in $g_1 : \mathbb{R}^{d} \to \mathbb{R}^{d_1}$, where the RHS notation means the gradient of $f_1$ evaluated at the point $(x, y-\nabla_y f_2(x+g_1(x,y), y))$.

This seems intractable in general, but all I need is to approximate $g_1$ numerically at any given point $(x,y)$ for any given functions $f_1, f_2$. I am not familiar with differential equations/functions defined implicitly; I heard about finite difference methods but can anyone help me through how to use them here? In particular I'm looking to implement this in Python.

Comment: It is a PDE, a non-linear one, as after applying all the chain rules it can be written as $0=F(x,y,g(x,y),g_x(x,y),g_y(x,y),g_{xy}(x,y))$ where $F$ contains no other "free" differentiation operators.

Comment: Is there a chain rule to be applied here? I specified that the notation means the gradient of $f_1$ evaluated at a new point, NOT the gradient of $f_1$ composed with the parameter update inside the brackets.

Comment: You could put parentheses around to restrict the reach of the operators, $(∇_xf_1)(x,y−...$ for emphasis of that interpretation. So your equation in the end is just algebraic, $g(x,y)=F(x,y,g(x,y))$. You should be able to implement this via `scipy.optimize.fsolve` or `find_root`, the partial derivatives can be computed as difference quotients or symbolically using `sympy`

Comment: @LutzLehmann The scipy method you suggest requires a function to be defined whose roots we wish to know, but $g$ is not known here, defined only implicitly in terms of itself... Any other suggestions?

Comment: You have $g_1(x,y)=u$ where $u$ is the solution is $F(x,y,u)-u=0$. This can be solved with a non-linear solver if sufficiently good initial approximations are available.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thank you, makes sense. Is there any way to guarantee that my equation has a unique solution for any fixed points $(x,y)$, i.e. that a root found by a non-linear solver is unique?

Comment: You could do path-following, either in the $(x,y)$-plane connecting the present situation to a reference point with reference solution, or by making a local homotopy in $u=F(x,y,\,t·u)$, where $t=0$ gives a trivial solution and following in steps to $t=1$ gives a unique solution if the path does not become singular. One may be able to navigate around such a singularity, but the solution obtained may now depend on how that is done.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I must admit I have no idea what you mean / how to do this! I will ask a separate question on MSE regarding uniqueness/existence of solutions to this implicit equation and reference it here. Would you like to post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?